# Kafka-streams application error using mapValue() method with Gson

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I write a kafka-streams application that getting data from topic "topic_one" (data had received from MySQL). Then I want to get a part (section "after", see below) of this data with KStream interface to make other operations. But I have an error with serialization then I use mapValue(). I am a new in kafka-streams and have no idea how to make and use a proper serde. Can anybody help me?

**Source data from topic_one:**

```
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"before": null, "after": {"id": 1, "category": 1, "item": "abc"}, "source": {"version": "0.8.3.Final", "name": "example", "server_id": 1, "ts_sec": 1581491071, "gtid": null, "file": "mysql-bin.000013", "pos": 217827349, "row": 0, "snapshot": false, "thread": 95709, "db": "example", "table": "item", "query": null}, "op": "c", "ts_ms": 1581491071727}
```

**I want to get:**

```
{"id": 1, "category": 1, "item": "abc"}
```

**My code:**

```
    Properties properties = getProperties();

    try {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> resourceStream = builder.stream("topic_one");
        resourceStream.print(Printed.toSysOut());

        KStream<String, String> resultStream = resourceStream.mapValues(value ->
                new Gson().fromJson(value, JsonObject.class).get("after").getAsJsonObject().toString());
        resultStream.print(Printed.toSysOut());

        Topology topology = builder.build();

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties);

        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static Properties getProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties(); // TODO настройки вынести в отдельный файл?

    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app_id");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");

    return properties;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "streams_id-db618fbf-c3e4-468b-a5a2-18e6b0b9c6be-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=matomo.matomo.matomo_scenarios_directory, partition=0, offset=30, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. **Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: unknown because key is null, and value: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record.
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.**
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:792)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:698)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:671)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream.lambda$withKey$1(AbstractStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:40)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:118)
    ... 10 more

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:792)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:698)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:671)
**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: unknown because key is null, and value: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record.**
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:429)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream.lambda$withKey$1(AbstractStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:40)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:118)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `getProperties()` method, you defined your value serde as `GenericAvroSerde.class`, but when you create the streams, you are using `String` as value type. That's why you get the exception at runtime.

```java
KStream<String, String> resourceStream = ...
KStream<String, String> resultStream = ...
```

If you really use Avro as message format, then you have the use the correct types, when defining you `KStream`. But as it seems, you have just JSON strings as values, so you can probably just set the correct value serde by replacing

```java
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
```

with

```java
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
```

Hope it helps.